# JQ JSON select with dynamic shell param

Tags: json, shell, jq

I use JQ for JSON formatting and filtering the data.

```
sed "s/.*Service - //p" tes.log | jq 'if (.requests | length) != 0 then .requests |= map(select(.orderId == "2260")) else "NO"  end' > ~/result.log
```

Here, the orderid is been hardcoded to 2260. But my requirement is to make it parameter driven.

So I store the param to a variable called ORDER_ID like,

```
ORDER_ID=2260
```

and then using $ORDER_ID, but it doesnt work.

```
sed "s/.*Service - //p" tes.log | jq 'if (.requests | length) != 0 then .requests |= map(select(.orderId == "$ORDER_ID")) else "NO"  end' > ~/result.log
```

It is not replacing the $ORDER_ID with the passed param.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell does not expand variables inside single quotes.  If `jq` is agnostic about the quote type, try swapping double and single quotes throughout.  Also, if you want to select only the line with `Service -` in it, you need the `-n` flag for sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*Service - //p' tes.log | jq "if (.requests | length) != 0 then .requests |= map(select(.orderId == '$ORDER_ID')) else 'NO' end" > ~/result.log
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please indent any lines of code with 4 spaces; it activates formatting which makes it more readable.

Comment: jq does not allow use of single quotes in literals.  See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926814/jq-json-select-with-dynamic-shell-param/45886023#45886023) below.

Answer (score 0):

As the following bash script demonstrates, [Stephen Gildea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4500538/stephen-gildea)'s example will not work because jq does not allow use of `'` single quotes.

```
#!/bin/bash
ORDER_ID=2260

jq "if (.requests | length) != 0 then .requests |= map(select(.orderId == '$ORDER_ID')) else 'NO' end" <<EOF
{"requests":[{"orderId":2260}]}
EOF
```

Specifically the `'NO'` literal will generate a syntax error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
if (.requests | length) != 0 then .requests |= map(select(.orderId == '2260')) else 'NO' end                                                                      
jq: error: Possibly unterminated 'if' statement at <top-level>, line 1:
if (.requests | length) != 0 then .requests |= map(select(.orderId == '2260')) else 'NO' end
jq: 2 compile errors
```

One approach which will work is to use the `--argjson` option, use single quotes for the entire jq filter and double quotes for strings literals within the filter.  E.g.

```
jq --argjson ORDER_ID "$ORDER_ID" '
if (.requests|length)!=0 then .requests |= map(select(.orderId == $ORDER_ID)) else "NO" end
'
```